# Wordpress rest api working all link except wp-json/wp/v2/users base link

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, litespeed

I post in wordpress from third party website. In this case I use Wordpress rest api with basic authentication. I verify wordpress site username and password with **wp-json/wp/v2/users/me** link. all wordpress site working good. but some website return **403 Forbidden. Access to this resource on the server is denied!** error on 'wp-json/wp/v2/users/me' and same website working with other rest api link (example: wp-json/wp/v2/posts). Even post are inserted.

- I allready try disable all plugin and change theme.
- I used Wordpress version 6.2.2
- web server: LiteSpeed
- php version: 8.2.28
- My user role is **Administrator**

my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

wp-config file

```
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the installation.
 * You don't have to use the web site, you can copy this file to "wp-config.php"
 * and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * Database settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * Localized language
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'dbname' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'user' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/**#@+
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',          'Q $k?/<E~X:<uFZ$QXj-0-Noz$+fF.Hb#[,xw,aqQQMi>XfhWJ;{Ao;yr?wSUpJM' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',   ':RLU9F:3I-;epD&qh%I|k,`90!x/JL/prYe2-_AWYN<g?y+7hq7#?P-[6tNFcn$e' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',     'I>E! U&895>bsuiM!)4OMn{Z-j3tVfB,PNo3w^p}*XV2OQj 61%d$t%H(B3(;HF_' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',         '3S fY#$nBEj_jc<l2=-<`zACn&6(uqbe2m7CCXxW:|;q(|wFL72wICd.8~}p^/TO' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',         'DP.LX^q(iarT7Q)J=9^D>Y$olOgya[N*8!#=LG.:7+R5 )x46}.D}>2NSzIBg-lY' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT',  '(1WIUG1xqcqTz/)bjs O16Jm-g$o#t#=TfQ!(=RfgS.`kyCXW)c2UtG?=>!B$B$U' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',    'jjKy$XdeP1CF^dm+LSz6XdJif3y#m{Bt=[#_t8W};|&8QkO%U({,]o0RMdHefWoJ' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',        'DzXo|IY)qa{bEQ)(wwW$EvQW_:ec&MHjl0a@0FBwEF0M.eVv_bg,Wx#HY=vAtAg&' );
define( 'WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', ':*L.;U|6_SD<M=_YOn{/%XbKN>0XILHeF#OiV17rqyGTT-5`08zc_Q7+k^E#oSEV' );


/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress database table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );


/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */



define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'minor' );
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```